# Get metadata from DOI

Tags: metadata, bibtex, doi

A [digital object identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_object_identifier) (DOI) is a globally unique string that identifies an electronic document (for example, a PDF of an academic article). It essentially provides a method for creating a permalink to a document (for example, http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/146585.146609).

Is there a web service (or any other system) to get the metadata (preferably in BibTeX form) of a document from a given DOI?

*Edited to add some expository information.*

Comment: I am not sure why this is closed either but there is information on this here http://crosscite.org/cn/

Comment: Since the question is closed, I will answer in the comments: `curl -LH "Accept: text/bibliography; style=bibtex" http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nrd842`

Comment: Also, look for JabRef.

Comment: @anumi Question's been reopened, if you want to convert your comment into an answer.

Comment: You know you are on Stack Exchange when it takes two years to reopen a question.

Comment: note that you can also get JSON `curl -LH "Accept: application/json" `

Answer (score 29):

[Section 5.4.1 Content Negotiation](http://www.doi.org/doi_handbook/5_Applications.html) of the DOI Handbook documents states, "Content negotiation is being implemented by DOI Registration Agencies for their DOI names, specifically to offer value-added metadata representations for users." According to [Section 4 Supported Content Types](http://citation.crosscite.org/docs.html#sec-4) of the DOI Content Negotiation documentation for http://crosscite.org, "Currently three DOI registration agencies have implemented content negotation for their DOIs: CrossRef, DataCite and mEDRA." The list of supported formats (which depends on the registration agency) includes both BibTeX via `Accept: application/x-bibtex` (this is the approach used by http://doi2bib.org) and formatted bibliography entry via `Accept: text/bibliography` (this is [the approach suggested by @anumi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34202810/108197) above). When using the latter header, you must specify the `style=bibtex` media type parameter.

The two relevant mimetypes provide slightly different representations. A request to `GET http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nrd842` with `Accept: application/x-bibtex` yields the response

```
@article{Atkins_2002,
    doi = {10.1038/nrd842},
    url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nrd842},
    year = 2002,
    month = {jul},
    publisher = {Springer Nature},
    volume = {1},
    number = {7},
    pages = {491--492},
    author = {Joshua H. Atkins and Leland J. Gershell},
    title = {From the analyst{\textquotesingle}s couch: Selective anticancer drugs},
    journal = {Nature Reviews Drug Discovery}
}
```

and with `Accept: text/bibliography; style=bibtex`

```
@article{Atkins_2002, title={From the analyst’s couch: Selective anticancer drugs}, volume={1}, ISSN={1474-1784}, url={http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nrd842}, DOI={10.1038/nrd842}, number={7}, journal={Nature Reviews Drug Discovery}, publisher={Springer Nature}, author={Atkins, Joshua H. and Gershell, Leland J.}, year={2002}, month={Jul}, pages={491–492}}
```

Comment: Great job putting this together! I would mark it as an answer, it's really helpful.

Answer (score 16):

`curl -LH "Accept: text/bibliography; style=bibtex" http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nrd842`

Comment: There is also doi2bib ("give us a DOI and we'll do our best to get you the BibTeX entry") at http://www.doi2bib.org/#/doi

Comment: Is this request/response interface documented somewhere? How did you find this functionality?

Comment: @argentpepper: sorry, I don't remember.

Comment: @argentpepper: Apparently it's official: https://www.crossref.org/labs/citation-formatting-service/

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at how these guys implemented it: www.doi2bib.org.

What I did in one of my projects:

- looked at their `url` request structure: `http://www.doi2bib.org/doi2bib` + `?id=` + `{your doi here}`.
- then used their... well `API` to get the data (e.g. http://www.doi2bib.org/doi2bib?id=10.1016%2Fj.actpsy.2016.09.007) and the response is:

  - `@article{Leinen_2016,
    doi = {10.1016/j.actpsy.2016.09.007},
    url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.actpsy.2016.09.007},
    year = 2016,
    month = {nov},
    publisher = {Elsevier {BV}},
    volume = {171},
    pages = {36--46},
    author = {Peter Leinen and Stefan Panzer and Charles H. Shea},
    title = {Hemispheric asymmetries of a motor memory in a recognition test after learning a movement sequence},
    journal = {Acta Psychologica}
    }`
- then you can parse it the way you want.

This helped me to get what I needed done. However, the nicest way would be to take a look at their [GitHub](https://github.com/davidagraf/doi2bib) repository and try to build your own.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! Their application seems to be making a request like that of @anumi above (`GET http://dx.doi.org/whatever`) but with the header `Accept: application/x-bibtex; charset=utf-8` instead of `Accept: text/bibliography; style=bibtex`. I will create a new answer with this info.

Comment: Doing something like `curl "http://www.doi2bib.org/doi2bib?id=<DOI>" doesn't work. What command did you use to get the output?

Answer (score 4):

CrossRef [has an API](http://search.crossref.org/help/api), which you can use with an API key that can be obtained free of charge from http://www.crossref.org/requestaccount/.

Comment: No longer available.

Comment: @IGP You don't have to register anymore. The API still works.

Answer (score 2):

Python implementation:

```
import requests

def get_doi_bibtex(doi):
  base_url = f"https://doi.org/{doi}"
  headers = {
      "Accept": "text/bibliography; style=bibtex"
  }
  response = requests.get(base_url, headers=headers)

  if response.status_code == 200:
    return response.text.strip()
  else:
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.text)
    return None

get_doi_bibtex("10.1109/xxxx")
```