# Why am I obtaining different results when running curl command from Terminal and in Java?

Tags: java, curl, groovy, metadata, doi

I have learned lots of suggestions to run `curl` in Java or its derivatives. For example, [curl command in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31049555/curl-command-in-java), [using curl command in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24053634/using-curl-command-in-java), etc.

Also, I have figured out how to [fetch the metadata of a given resource using DOI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507049/get-metadata-from-doi). From this instruction, I am very interested in running this curl command using a small snippet in Java to handle the result.

Let's give an example. The URL is `http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.immuni.2015.09.001`.

**Running curl command from a terminal**

`curl -LH "Accept: application/x-bibtex" http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.immuni.2015.09.001`

The output looks like

```
@article{Biswas_2015,
    doi = {10.1016/j.immuni.2015.09.001},
    url = {https://doi.org/10.1016%2Fj.immuni.2015.09.001},
    year = 2015,
    month = {sep},
    publisher = {Elsevier {BV}},
    volume = {43},
    number = {3},
    pages = {435--449},
    author = {Subhra~K. Biswas},
    title = {Metabolic Reprogramming of Immune Cells in Cancer Progression},
    journal = {Immunity}
```

**Running this curl command in Groovy**

Recycling some codes sharing on this site, I have written the process as below.

```
Map result = [:]
String command = "curl -LH 'Accept: application/x-bibtex' http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.immuni.2015.09.001"
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)
InputStream stream = process.getInputStream()
result.put("data", stream.text)
process.destroy()
```

What I obtain is the whole page in HTML rather than a BibTeX formatted form as what is my expectation.

**The question is: what am I doing wrong here? Are there any of you that have experienced with that issue?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `exec` is not a shell - you can't and don't have to quote for
a shell, that is not there.  Further `exec(String)` uses by default
a string tokenizer (which basically splits at whitespace) to make it
particularly useless for any slightly advanced usecase.

You are most likely always better off to use the version that accepts
a string array for the command (+ args).

What you where effectively calling looked like this (note, that the
command gets split at whitespace -- so I used `\'` to make my shell
ignore that):

```
# curl -LH \'Accept: application/x-bibtex\' http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.immuni.2015.09.001
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
... HTML ...
```

The shortest route using groovy looks like this (note that `exec` also
has a version for passing in an array of strings):

```
groovy:000> ["curl", "-LH", "Accept: application/x-bibtex", "http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.immuni.2015.09.001"].execute().text
===> @article{Biswas_2015,
9doi = {10.1016/j.immuni.2015.09.001},
9url = {https://doi.org/10.1016%2Fj.immuni.2015.09.001},
9year = 2015,
9month = {sep},
9publisher = {Elsevier {BV}},
9volume = {43},
9number = {3},
9pages = {435--449},
9author = {Subhra~K. Biswas},
9title = {Metabolic Reprogramming of Immune Cells in Cancer Progression},
9journal = {Immunity}
}
```

If you need "shell-isms", then use `["sh", "-c", command]` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The important point here is to use Groovy idiomatic statements to execute rather Java's styles.

Comment: Btw, do you know the equivalent Java version for the same purpose?

Comment: Pass an array of strings instead of the string